Shouldn't the User Story status be updated during the sprint in case of issues?
If a user story fails during testing, should we communicate the issues to the developers via group chats, document them in the user story while keeping it open, or fail the story and return it to the dev team?
Our company has a team that conducts end-to-end testing before the release. I believe updating the user story status and documenting any issues, questions, and confirmations is the best approach. This ensures clarity and allows others to benefit from shared insights, especially if they have similar inquiries.
What is considered the best practice in Agile?

We can answer this question as part of SQA community as well. Please don't vote as off-topic.

There is no "best practice in Agile". Key values and principles of Agile Software Development focus on how people interact and collaborate to deliver working software frequently. Different teams and organizations will find various ways to work within their context and constraints.
That said, there may be some good practices. Many, if not most, people would agree that recording, tracking, and managing the results of verification and validation activities is a good practice. That implies there needs to be communication between the people finding the issues and those triaging and/or resolving the problems, especially if they are different people. There's also an implication of writing something down to understand where issues are coming from and how to improve to detect or prevent problems.
I've worked with teams with different approaches, all of which worked for the teams at the time. Some teams were very informal - using email or chat tools to communicate about issues as work progressed through the workflow. Other teams were a little more formal and used commenting functionality on the issue, creating a slightly more robust paper trail. Some teams created subtasks on the story issue to indicate undone work. Other teams created new issues in the issue-tracking tool.
The best people to figure out the approach are the people involved in the process - the people finding, reporting, triaging, fixing the problems, and monitoring the processes associated with quality assurance and quality control. Depending on the organizational structures, this would likely include testers, product managers, developers, and perhaps leads or managers.

Thanks for sharing your experience, Thomas! I definitely gained more insights into agile culture.

Yes, that's true as mentioned by @Thomas.
There is no best practices in agile, It varies company to company.
Coming to your question, I would recommend:

If you found that the story fails during testing that means some/all of the AC's are not working as per the given/expected requirement, in that case you can mark the failing TC's as FAILED (attaching detailed screens/steps/information in results) in JIRA/Rally or whichever tool your are using.

You can mark story to 'Reopen' and assign it to the Developer. (this will get better clarity for Scrum master while reviewing sprint Dashboard)

The same info you can post it in story comments section tagging it to the Dev/SM or concern team members for better clarity that these many TC's are failing with details.

Yes, if you have separate communication channel/group then definitely communicate about the story status in the group stating - During story testing "story Number" is Reopen and TC1, TC2, TC3... are FAILING, please find the detailed steps and info the TC results.

Other way is to connect with Dev team member and discuss on the steps to reproduce the Failed TC, or why the TC's are failing.

Some companies are logging a BUG against each failing TC's and then tracking those to get it fixed with dev team.


All these points are not mentioned anywhere as a Agile Best practices, It varies team to team and company to company. As a Scrum Team we can set the standard process/approach.

Thank you very much for such insightful comment.
